# can you waste google adds through automation

Tags: selenium, vpn

suppose company Z pays google adds such that their adds stay on the front page of the results until it has been clicked on x amount of times, what would stop me creating a selenium webscraper that clicks over and over to waste those views?

if there is something to stop me, could I not easily overcome that by using a VPN and being a bit more random with my webscraper so it doesn't seem robotic?

is that even legal?

alternative:
suppose i run a vpn on my computer, open a vm and run a vpn on my vm, click  the add once. close my vm, delete it and create a new one. open the new one and download a vpn, then click on the add again from inside a second vm in a new vpn?

would that be 2 clicks?

Comment: Legal, probably. Clicking on adverts if competitors is legal, because that's just inevitable. But google probably has mechanisms to stop you from doing this or not paying the competitor for fake clicks . Anyway, if someone finds out about this, then that won't be too great. _I am not a lawyer, and this isn't legal advice_

Answer (score 1):

Basically by connecting through a VPN you would get a new IP a forward your traffic to this IP. So the website you are connected to would see you under the new IP.

However, you would still have single IP which will register the first click to your add but won't trigger any other click since it would come from the same IP and being detected by the google anticheat system.

Comment: ok, so what if i run a vpn on my computer, open a vm  and run a vpn on that, click  the add once. close my vm, delete it and create a new one. open the new one and download a vpn, then click again from inside a second vm in a new vpn?

Comment: Besides the legal aspect which I am not expert on, your VPN provider has a limited number of actual servers and therefore of IP addresses. So maybe you would get it working one or two times with the VPN dispatcher giving you another IP ; but at some point you **will** (and pretty quickly) get stuck to the same point of being rejected by the google antibot.